# C# + PostScript

Tags: c#

Is there a way to implement PostScript like page display for text files in C#??

ie a Print Preview for a bunch of text in a web page.
The requirement is to show a Print Preview like in Google Docs for a text displayed inside a label.

Comment: Should the preview be a precise copy of printed page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostScript is a programming language with a set of operators/functions which generate output.

Much like C# + System.Drawing.

So the answer is Yes.

I would suggest starting by looking at how to transform your input into HTML. But need the details of the input format to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

With your input values, you can create Postscript syntax to draw shapes/display text.